# Get all data of one row by click on a Button?

Tags: android, listview, row

I use below code for get data of one row

```
View vListSortOrder;

    vListSortOrder=getListView().getChildAt(MyPositionOfRow);     

    TextView edit=(TextView)vListSortOrder.findViewById(R.id.MyLabelId);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), edit.getText(), 1).show();
```

But My problem is item that not shown in the listView
for Ex: I have 20 item .In MyPhone Screen 10 item of ListView displays.
when `MyPositionOfRow` set to `0_9` not problem.
when `MyPositionOfRow` set to `10` or above my program will be crash
How fix it?
Or other way to get data of one row in listView.

Answer (score 0):

**You have to use Adapter for interaction with ListView**

Your application is crashing, because during UI execution in memory existed only 9 items of ListView.

If you will scroll list to the up - upper item moves to the bottom for memory reducing. And we have to use adapter for correct changing of the item's content.

Really nice article you can find here:
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html